# phpseclib not works with php5-cli from terminal

Tags: php, debian, rsa, raspbian, phpseclib

I installed php5-cli package on my raspbian (debian OS) and I downloaded [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/intro.html) in /cli/ directory.
I created a test file to encrypt text with a public key (generated within my apache server on which I have the same library) in this way:

```
    include('libs/Crypt/RSA.php');
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->loadKey($myPublicKey);
    $encrypted = $rsa->encrypt("my text");
    echo "result: " .$encrypted;
```

If I try to type *php test.php* the `result` variable is empty. Why? It's due to the fact I execute the file from terminal e with php5-cli instead of php5 ?
How Can I obtain the result of this encrypting operation?
Thanks.

Comment: thank to @JanC and @Sammitch! It was an uncorrect key. Now all works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code you have provided is correct. If the value of `$encrypted` is empty, it's possible due to an incorrect key supplied in `loadKey`.

According to the comments in the file `RSA.php`, then the command will return `false` if the key is invalid:

```
/**
 * Loads a public or private key
 *
 * Returns true on success and false on failure (ie. an incorrect password was provided or the key was malformed)
 *
 * @access public
 * @param String $key
 * @param Integer $type optional
 */
function loadKey($key, $type = false){
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure `error_reporting` is on, and turned up high enough.
2. Try `var_dump($encrypted)` instead of echoing. PHPseclib's documentation is a bit lacking, and it doesn't detail the behaviour of the Crypt_RSA::encrypt() function *on failure*. It could be returning `false`,`NULL`, or an empty string, and `echo` isn't going to tell you which.