# $rsa->encrypt() has problems with my public key

Tags: php, rsa, phpseclib, rsa-key-fingerprint

I'm trying to encrypt some things with `phpseclib` but for some reason the `encrypt()` function does not return anything.

Here is the core I have now:

```
include('/pathto/Crypt/RSA.php');

$key = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($key);

$sometext = 'test this text';

echo $rsa->encrypt($sometext);
```

I downloaded the version 1.0.

What is wrong?

---

I dug a little deeper and found [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20689058/10169071) and changed a part of my test code to this:

```
if (!$rsa->encrypt($sometext)) {
    echo "false";
} else {
    echo $rsa->encrypt($sometext);
}
```

This proves that my key is somehow wrong. But how should the format be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RSA public key is actually an X509 cert. It *contains* a public key but isn't, in and of itself, a public key. I was able to get your code sample working by doing this:

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');

$key = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->loadX509($key);
$rsa = $x509->getPublicKey();

$sometext = 'test this text';

echo $rsa->encrypt($sometext);
```

Comment: You have pointed me in the right direction. Thanks for that! I also needed to include the `Crypt/RSA.php` and 
`$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($pkey);
echo $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);`
to get it working!